# Calling function from another file

Tags: c

I need to call function in file Dist.c in switch from files DB.c and ListOfCity.c but VS 2010 gives me error:
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'. (on line under every case)
When I compile project as C++ (instead of C, but I need C not C++) I can run compiled exe file, but when I enter the number 1 or 2 it only show "Press any key to continue." and don't run the function. Thanks in advance!

file Dist.c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include "db.h"

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int choice;
    do {
        printf("[1] Index of city\n[2] Add city to end some next\Your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                void PrintCity();
        system("pause");
        break;
            case 2:
                AddOnEnd();
        system("pause");
        break;

            ..... 

            default:
                printf("Another numer.\n");
        system("pause");
        break;

        break;
        }
    } while (volba != 0);
```

file DB.h

```
#include "ListOfCity.h"
typedef struct Database {
    int numberOfCity;
    tListOfCity* list;
    double **distances;
} tDatabase;

tDatabase *LoadDatabase(char* file);
void DeleteDatabase(tDatabase* db);
int GiveIndexCity(tDatabase* db, char* city);
double GiveDistanceBetweenCities(tDatabase* db ,char* city1, char* city2);
double CountDistance(tDatabase* db, tListOfCity* list);
void PrintDistance(tDatabaze* db, tListOfCity* list);
```

file ListOfCity.h

```
#define LENGTH 60

typedef struct ListOfCity {
    char city[LENGTH];
    struct ListOfCity* next;
} tListOfCity;

tListOfCity* CreateCity(char* city);
tListOfCity *AddOnEnd(tListOfCity* list, tListOfCity* new);
void PrintCity(tListOfCity* list);
```

Comment: Can you show us what line is giving you the compilation error?

Comment: Did you mean to say "PrintCity();" instead of "void PrintCity();"?

Comment: @JaredPar in file Dist.C, line with void PrintCity(); and AddOnEnd();

Answer (score 2):

Your `AddOnEnd()` declaration takes 2 parameters:

```
tListOfCity *AddOnEnd(tListOfCity* list, tListOfCity* new);
```

but your function call doesn't pass any???

```
AddOnEnd();
```

Additionally,

```
void PrintCity();
```

Declares a function, it does not call a function.

Comment: so should I write it 
"AddOnEnd(tListOfCity* list, tListOfCity* new);" 
instead of 
"AddOnEnd();"
or how?